# How to remove hardcoded subtitles from a movie file?

Tags: video, subtitles

I downloaded a movie in MP4 format, which has japanesse subtitles hardcoded in the video. How can I remove these subtitles in order to use czech subtitles downloaded in SRT format without being distracted by the japanesse ones that feel to rush the movie for me? Is there any freeware software that can do similar job like Photoshop's Content Aware fill over selected areas (which would be the subtitles in this case)? Or just simply cover the subtitles with black rectangles? VirtualDub with downloaded subtitles removal plugin can't recognise asian charactes...

Comment: Are you sure they're subtitles, rather than being part of each frame image?  If the latter, only a black rectangle will do the job,and you may as well crop off the bottom 1/10 of the screen (it'll take a lot less of your time than inserting black rectangles only where needed) and use that blank space for your Czech subtitles.

Comment: I can't crop the movie frame as it is already in cinema scope format. They're hardcoded to the video, so this means that these subtitles are part of the video image and such part of frames that contain subtitles. In short I can't disable these subtitles or remove them usual way from the file stream. The VLC player already shows up czech subtitles downloaded, but they just overlay the japanesse ones. If there's no easy and quick way, then I just have to leave them there. So shame :(

Comment: there is nothing that can be done about hard subs, except to paint over them frame by frame in a video editor. There may be softare that attempts this, but it will be far from perfect.  In your case, you can probalby tell VLC to place the soft czech subs somewhere else on the screen, thought that is suboptimal, I know.

Comment: Ask the owner to provide it without the subtitles

Comment: @Dave I'm afraid that won't help. Another solution is to download from another source. I'm trying out torrents, but I don't want to upload - just download. Maybe I could try out many ways of obtaining the right version...